# fabricjs: text alignment issue while using export and import as svg

Tags: canvas, svg, fabricjs

Text added on the canvas once exported as SVG and imported to canvas, is not aligning the same way as it's original

http://jsbin.com/ruluko/edit?html,js,output

using fabric js v1.6.0-rc.1

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a bug in fabric's svg parser.
You can see it if, instead of grouping the svg elements, you add them one by one :

```js
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('c1');
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  fill: '#eef'
});
canvas1.add(circle);
var text = new fabric.Text('fabric', { fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 100 });
canvas1.add(text);
var topText = new fabric.Text('Top', { fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 0 });
canvas1.add(topText);
var botText = new fabric.Text('Bot LL', { fill: 'red', left: 80, top: 163 });
canvas1.add(botText);

var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2');

var doAction = function() {
  var mysvg = canvas1.toSVG();
  canvas2.clear();
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(mysvg, function(objects, options) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      canvas2.add(objects[i]);
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.canvas-container{border:1px solid; display: inline-block; position: relative;}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/fabric.js/1.6.0-rc.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

  <canvas id="c1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
  <canvas id="c2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
  <button onclick='doAction()'>Export & Import as SVG</button>
```

As you can see in the snippet, each element's box is at the wrong coordinates.
Note that it also occurs with the `loadSVGFromURL()` method.

---

One quick workaround if you were going to group those elements anyway, is to draw your svg as an image :

```js
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('c1');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  fill: '#eef'
});
canvas1.add(circle);
var text = new fabric.Text('fabric', { fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 100 });
canvas1.add(text);
var topText = new fabric.Text('Top', { fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 0 });
canvas1.add(topText);
var botText = new fabric.Text('Bot LL', { fill: 'red', left: 80, top: 163 });
canvas1.add(botText);

var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2');


var doAction = function() {
  var mysvg = canvas1.toSVG();
  canvas2.clear();
  var svgURL = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(mysvg.split('svg11.dtd">')[1]);
  fabric.Image.fromURL(svgURL, function(oImg) {
    canvas2.add(oImg)
  });
};
```

```css
.canvas-container{border:1px solid; display: inline-block; position: relative;}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/fabric.js/1.6.0-rc.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<button onclick='doAction()'>Export & Import as SVG</button>
```

The main caveat of this workaround is that you will lose ability to modify each path of your group once loaded.

---

Since the problem occurs because of `<tspan>` elements, a better fix would be to first clean your svg string, by replacing all those `<tspan>` to `<text>` elements :

```js
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('c1');

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  fill: '#eef'
});
canvas1.add(circle);
var text = 'this is\na multiline\ntext';
var alignedRightText = new fabric.Text(text, {
  textAlign: 'right'
});
canvas1.add(alignedRightText)
var topText = new fabric.Text('Top', { fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 0 });
canvas1.add(topText);
var botText = new fabric.Text('Bot LL', { fill: 'red', left: 80, top: 163 });
canvas1.add(botText);

var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2');


var doAction = function() {
  var mysvg = canvas1.toSVG();
  canvas2.clear();
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(fixSVGText(mysvg), function(objects, options) {
    options.selectable = false;
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvas2.add(obj).renderAll();
  });
};

function fixSVGText(str) {
  // parse our string as a DOM object and get the SVGElement
  var svg = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "image/svg+xml").documentElement;

  // get all <tspan> elements
  var tspans = svg.querySelectorAll('tspan');
  for (var i = 0; i < tspans.length; i++) {
    var ts = tspans[i],
      parent = ts.parentNode,
      gParent = parent.parentNode;
    var j = 0;

    // create a new SVGTextElement to replace our tspan
    var replace = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');

    var tsAttr = ts.attributes;
    // set the 'x', 'y' and 'fill' attributes to our new element
    for (j = 0; j < tsAttr.length; j++) {
      replace.setAttributeNS(null, tsAttr[j].name, tsAttr[j].value);
    }

    // append the contentText
    var childNodes = ts.childNodes;
    for (j = 0; j < childNodes.length; j++) {
      replace.appendChild(ts.childNodes[j]);
    }

    var tAttr = parent.attributes;
    // set the original text attributes to our new one
    for (j = 0; j < tAttr.length; j++) {
      replace.setAttributeNS(null, tAttr[j].name, tAttr[j].value);
    }
    // append our new text to the grand-parent
    gParent.appendChild(replace);

    // if this is the last tspan
    if (ts === parent.lastElementChild)
    // remove the old, now empty, SVGTextElement
      gParent.removeChild(parent)
  }
  // return a string version of our cleaned svg
  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
}
```

```css
.canvas-container{border:1px solid; display: inline-block; position: relative;}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/fabric.js/1.6.0-rc.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<button onclick='doAction()'>Export & Import as SVG</button>
```

But the best solution is still to [open a new issue to kangax](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues?q=is%3Aopen+sort%3Acreated-desc), and hope that this bug will be fixed in future versions.

Comment: I have tried this option, but this reduces the quality of the exported data right?

Comment: @CodingNinja, No, this is still svg drawn on a canvas. What you lose is the ability to control each path in the group independently.

Comment: @CodingNinja added an other (heavier but cleaner) way to workaround the issue. It actually parse the svg string once and remove the buggy elements (`<tspan>`).

Comment: I tried it and... "NamespaceError: An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces". Specific line: `replace.setAttributeNS(null, tAttr[j].name, tAttr[j].value);`, . However the demo on stackoverflow works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate finding your solution Moussa. Thank you.

I noticed for multiline text boxes, that solution is only grabbing the last line. Below is a solution I worked out starting from your code. The alignment is still funky for that, but at least this looks like a step in the right direction:

```
function convertTspans(svg) {
    var tspans = svg.match(/<\s*tspan[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*tspan>/g);

    var x = null;
    var y = null;
    var groupString = null;
    var matrixString = null;
    var xMatrix = null;
    var yMatrix = null;
    var transformedSvg = svg;

    if (tspans === null) {
        return svg;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tspans.length; i++) {
        var tspanString = tspans[i];
        var text = tspanString.replace(/<\s*tspan[^>]*>/g, '');
        var text = text.replace(/<\s*\/tspan[^>]*>/g, '');

        var coordMatch = tspanString.match(/x="(-?\d*\.?\d+)" y="(-?\d*\.?\d+)"/);

        if (coordMatch && coordMatch.length > 2) {
            x = parseFloat(coordMatch[1]);
            y = parseFloat(coordMatch[2]);
        }

        var groupTagMatch = svg.match(/<g transform.*>/);

        if (groupTagMatch) {
            groupString = groupTagMatch[0];

            // groupString is like <g transform="matrix(a b c d e f)" style=""  > where e = xMatrix et f = yMatrix
            var matrixMatch = groupString.match(/matrix\((-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+)\)/);

            if (matrixMatch && matrixMatch.length > 6) {
                matrixString = matrixMatch[0];
                xMatrix = parseFloat(matrixMatch[5]);
                yMatrix = parseFloat(matrixMatch[6]);

                if (x !== null 
                    && y !== null 
                    && xMatrix !== null 
                    && yMatrix !== null 
                    && text !== null 
                    && groupString !== null 
                    && matrixString !== null
                ) {

                    var newMatrixString = 'matrix(' + matrixMatch[1] + ' ' + matrixMatch[2] + ' ' + matrixMatch[3] + ' ' + matrixMatch[4] + ' ' +
                        (x + xMatrix) + ' ' + (y + yMatrix) + ')';

                    transformedSvg = svg
                        .replace(matrixString, newMatrixString)
                        .replace(tspanString, text);

                    console.log('--> svg', svg);
                    console.log('--> transformedSvg', transformedSvg);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return transformedSvg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toSVG) there is a call back to the method `toSVG` when you export the SVG :

> Modify SVG output with reviver function

So a solution would be to remove all `<tspan></tspan>` during export with this call back and adjust the coordinate of the group that contains the text tag. When you export instead of calling `canvas.toSVG()` you call `canvas.toSVG(null, deleteTspan)`. This solution has been tested with version 2.4.6 and for me it works fine.

Here is a sample of code, I think it can be cleaner but it does the job for me :

```
function deleteTspan(svg) {
    var tspanTagMatch = svg.match(/<tspan.*>(.*)<\/tspan>/);

    var tspanString = null;
    var text = null;
    var x = null;
    var y = null;
    var groupString = null;
    var matrixString = null;
    var xMatrix = null;
    var yMatrix = null;
    var transformedSvg = svg;
    if (tspanTagMatch && tspanTagMatch.length > 1) {
        text = tspanTagMatch[1];

        tspanString = tspanTagMatch[0];
        var coordMatch = tspanString.match(/x="(-?\d*\.?\d+)" y="(-?\d*\.?\d+)"/);
        if (coordMatch && coordMatch.length > 2) {
            x = parseFloat(coordMatch[1]);
            y = parseFloat(coordMatch[2]);
        }

        var groupTagMatch = svg.match(/<g transform.*>/);
        if (groupTagMatch) {
            groupString = groupTagMatch[0];

            // groupString is like <g transform="matrix(a b c d e f)" style=""  > where e = xMatrix et f = yMatrix
            var matrixMatch = groupString.match(/matrix\((-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+) (-?\d*\.?\d+)\)/);
            if (matrixMatch && matrixMatch.length > 6) {
                matrixString = matrixMatch[0];
                xMatrix = parseFloat(matrixMatch[5]);
                yMatrix = parseFloat(matrixMatch[6]);

                if (x !== null && y !== null && xMatrix !== null && yMatrix !== null &&
                    text !== null && tspanString !== null && groupString !== null && matrixString !== null) {

                    var newMatrixString = 'matrix(' + matrixMatch[1] + ' ' + matrixMatch[2] + ' ' + matrixMatch[3] + ' ' + matrixMatch[4] + ' ' +
                        (x + xMatrix) + ' ' + (y + yMatrix) + ')';

                    transformedSvg = svg
                        .replace(matrixString, newMatrixString)
                        .replace(tspanString, text);

                    console.log('--> svg', svg);
                    console.log('--> transformedSvg', transformedSvg);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return transformedSvg;
}
```

Comment: I don't get an error from this one, but it doesn't output the text in the .svg file in the right location.